# Python websockets error gaierror

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to write a websocket that connects to a service running on localhost but it's throwing an error

```
>>> from websocket import create_connection
>>> ws = create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1", http_proxy_port="2974", http_proxy_host="quividicontent")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    ws = create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1", http_proxy_port="2974", http_proxy_host="quividicontent")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\websocket\_core.py", line 487, in create_connection
    websock.connect(url, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\websocket\_core.py", line 211, in connect
    options.pop('socket', None))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\websocket\_http.py", line 64, in connect
    hostname, port, is_secure, proxy)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\websocket\_http.py", line 97, in _get_addrinfo_list
    addrinfo_list = socket.getaddrinfo(phost, pport, 0, 0, socket.SOL_TCP)
gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
>>> ws = create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1", http_proxy_port="2974")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    ws = create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1", http_proxy_port="2974")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\websocket\_core.py", line 487, in create_connection
    websock.connect(url, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\websocket\_core.py", line 214, in connect
    self.handshake_response = handshake(self.sock, *addrs, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\websocket\_handshake.py", line 65, in handshake
    status, resp = _get_resp_headers(sock)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\websocket\_handshake.py", line 122, in _get_resp_headers
    raise WebSocketBadStatusException("Handshake status %d", status)
WebSocketBadStatusException: Handshake status 200
>>> import socket
>>> socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', 2974)
[(23, 0, 0, '', ('::1', 2974, 0, 0)), (2, 0, 0, '', ('127.0.0.1', 2974))]
```

I'm sure the port is open and listening, used sockets and a more complex example with the `onOpen` `onMessage` function works.

Comment: Can you try to update your `create_connection` with `"ws://127.0.0.1:2974" `. And eventually, if you have a ressource, with  `"ws://127.0.0.1:2974/your/ressource" `

Comment: Returns the same error `gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed`

Comment: Are you sure the service you are trying to connect can manage websocket ?

Comment: pretty sure this script http://pastebin.com/1h1SuVnp connects and starts printing (throws no error)

Comment: Maybe you should try to specify a protocol in your connection as it may be needed to the handshake with a websocket. `ws = websocket.create_connection("ws://exapmle.com/websocket", subprotocols=["binary", "base64"])` in your cas it could be `['quividicontent']` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue occurs because you need to specify a protocol for the handshake with the websocket.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Protocol_handshake) :

> To establish a WebSocket connection, the client sends a WebSocket
>   handshake request, for which the server returns a WebSocket handshake
>   response, as shown in the example below.

During this handshake, the server and the client discuss about what protocols should be used and if there is no protocol specified, this could lead to an error (not always).

From the python-websocket doc, specify a protocol can be done with 
 :

```
ws = websocket.create_connection("ws://exapmle.com/websocket", subprotocols=["binary", "base64"])
```

In your particular case, `subprotocols` should be `['quividicontent']`